# Is it possible to print the awk output in the same line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

The awk output looks like:

```
awk '{print $2}'
toto
titi
tata
```

I want to dispay the output of awk in the same line with space as separator instead of new line

```
awk [option] '{print $2}'
toto titi tata
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

From the manpage:

```
ORS         The output record separator, by default a newline.
```

Therefore,

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS=" " }; { print $2 }' file
```

Comment: I would have written it like this `awk '{print $2}' ORS=" " file`, but this is more of choice of what you like.

Answer (score 32):

You can always use  `printf` to control the output of `awk`

```
awk '{printf "%s ",$2}' file
toto titi tata
```

Answer (score 5):

OR you can use `paste`

```
awk '{print $2}' FILE |paste -sd " "
```

Answer (score 3):

My option is the same as accepted answer but I believe my command is a bit easy to remember.

`awk '{print $2 }' ORS=' '`